# Rails: find_each(:include => :user ) never gets the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, include, find, associations

I have two models

```
class User
  has_one :entry
end

class Entry
  belongs_to: user
end
```

in my controller I use find_each to iterate over entries to email each of the users.

```
 Entry.find_each(:include => :user, :conditions => {:approved => true}) do |entry|
    UserMailer.send_competition_open_email(entry, entry.user)
 end
```

**entry.user** is always **nil**. ":include => :user" never finds the user.

yet i can see in my SQL logs it tries to get it. But fails. Any ideas?

```
Entry Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries` WHERE `entries`.`approved` = 1 AND (`entries`.`id` >= 0) ORDER BY `entries`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1000
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` IN (1,2,3))
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Entry
  belongs_to: user
end
```

Just a quick check that you noticed the colon is butting "belongs_to" and not "user"?